# How to use bulk import in SQL Server using files from Google Big Query?

Tags: sql-server, google-bigquery

I'm importing 700 files that, when put together, represent a 1.2Billion record table that was analyzed and exported in Big Query.

Using SSIS, or the Import/Export wizard, I was able to import the first file to create the structure of the table below.  Because it takes 30-45 minutes PER file in a regular transfer, I'm trying to work "bulk import".

My Current Command:

```
BULK INSERT mother.dbo.Mother      FROM 'F:\Data\Consumer\New Consumer\Mother\Mother_000000000000.csv'      WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = ''+CHAR(10)+'', KEEPNULLS );
```

I'm getting errors that indicate I have the ROWTERMINATOR wrong:

> Msg 4866, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The bulk load failed. The column
>   is too long in the data file for row 1, column 45. Verify that the
>   field terminator and row terminator are specified correctly. Msg 7399,
>   Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server
>   "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information
>   about the error. Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 Cannot fetch a
>   row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".

I'm being told that this is due to a bad `ROWTERMINATOR`. Notepad++ says `LF`.  To date, I've tried:

```
 \n
 0x0A
 0x0a
 lf
 LF
 CHAR(10)  <--example above
```

Has anyone imported BigQuery exports into SQL Server before using bulk import? and if so, what is the proper syntax?  Thanks.

## TABLE DEFINITION

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Mother](
    [FirstName] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [LastName] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [MiddleName] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [Gender] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [Age] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [DOB] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [Address] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [Address2] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [City] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [State] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [Zip] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [Zip4] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [TimeZone] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [Income] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [HomeValue] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [Networth] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [MaritalStatus] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [IsRenter] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [HasChildren] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [CreditRating] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [Investor] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [LinesOfCredit] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [InvestorRealEstate] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [Traveler] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [Pets] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [MailResponder] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [Charitable] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [PolicalDonations] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [PoliticalParty] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [Attom_ID] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [GEOID] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [Score] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [Score1] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [Score2] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [Score3] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [Score4] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [Score5] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [Latitude] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [Longitude] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [Email1] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [Email2] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [Email3] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [Phone1] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [Phone2] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [Phone3] [varchar](500) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Thanks much!.  Unfortunately, the data coming in is personal data, and I can't put it on here for example.

Comment: Are you getting header row/rows in the CSV file?

Comment: no.  I don't see them.  Thanks

Comment: BULK INSERT dbo.test FROM 'F:\test_records.txt'      
WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a', KEEPNULLS); seems to be working fine at my end.

Comment: same response: `Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 3
Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".`

Comment: Copy 10 rows from the file and create a new csv file with 10 records and see if that's loading. There might be some issue in the big file.

Comment: ok.  10 rows worked.  This scares me, because we have 700 files.  How do I find out what happened?

Comment: I think the address fields (Address, Address2) might have a comma(,) in the text which is causing the failure because of more number of columns in that particular record.

Comment: ok.  I changed the delimiter to dollar sign($), and still have the errors.

Comment: How did you change the delimiter, in the file itself or you created the new file with the new delimiter from the source?

Comment: created new files from source.  bq extract -F$ <source> <destination>

Comment: I hope there is no chance of having $s in the data (you know your data better, there are Money columns in the table), also check whether the last line has the row terminator or not.

Comment: no.  not that I can tell.

Comment: again...765 Mil records, but as far as I know there shouldn't be any

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Comment: not yet.  still digging about trying different methods.....give me another 6 hours.  Someone mentioned that GBQ outputs UTF-8, and that could cause a bulk insert failure in itself.  So I'm looking into that.